# How can I prevent a marker being dropped when the map is dragged in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers, angular

I am using Leaflet to display a map in Angular8.
I want to add a marker to the clicked location.
Everything works fine, except the fact that a marker is being added after I finish dragging the map, and I do not know how to prevent that.

My .html file looks like this:

```
<div id="mycontainer" class="container">
  <div class="map-container">
    <div class="map-frame">
      <div id="map"  (click)="addMarker($event)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my addMarker function looks like:

```
addMarker(event){
let latlng = this.map.mouseEventToLatLnt(event);
L.marker([latlng['lat'],latlng['lng']]).addTo(this.map);
}
```

I have tried checking if the mouseEvent movement attributes are different from 0, but it didnt have any effect.
I also tried to use a Boolean which would be set to false on dragstart and to 
true dragend/dragleave/dragexit event of the map, but none of that worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about managing your event handlers.  I'm going to remove the HTML into onclick function and do it all in one place in the js:

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

What we'll do is add an event listener to the map that listens for a `mousedown` event.  Once that mousedown is heard, we will listen for one of two events on the map: either a mouseup, or a drag.

```js
// Add initial event listener to map for a mouse down
leafletMap.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){

  // Start listening for a mouseup event
  leafletMap.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler)

  // Also start listening for a drag event
  leafletMap.addEventListener('drag', dragHandler)

})
```

Each handler has its own job.  If a mouseup is heard without any drag being heard first, it will fire off your function to place a marker at that point.  If a drag event is heard first, it will simply remove the 'mouseup' eventlistener from the map.

```js
function mouseupHandler(e){
  placeMarker(e)
  cleanUpEventListeners()
}

function dragHandler(){
  cleanUpEventListeners()
}


function placeMarker(e){
  L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(leafletMap)
}

function cleanUpEventListeners(){
  leafletMap.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler)
  leafletMap.removeEventListener('drag', dragHandler)
}
```

You'll notice that regardless of whether the mouseup or drag is heard first, it calls `cleanUpEventListeners`, which removes the two eventlisteners from the map.  If we don't do this, then every time the map hears a mousedown, it will add those eventlisteners again, and we end up attaching a bunch of eventlisteners again and again.

[Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-marker-drag-problem-dq4eq) with some console.log statements in each handler so you can track what is happening.